# Fill array with zero values in a a given range

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I am working on laravel 5.3 and Here is my code

```
$arrayData = array();
foreach ($stats as $key => $row) {
      $arrayData[] = array(
      'number'   => $row->no,
      'level'    => $row->total_sent,
      'past'     => $row->past,
  );
}
```

if i `dd($arrayData)` its output is as

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "4"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "6"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "9"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
]
```

Here in above no are 4,6,9 respectively.
I want final out output should contain complete data.
If no exits that's fine other wise numbers should be with zero.

In above case, desired output is as
at missing position there will be a correct number with zero values

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "0"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "1"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "2"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "3"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "4"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "5"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "6"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "7"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "8"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "9"
    "level" => 3
    "past" => "3"
  ]
  10 => array:3 [▼
    "no" => "10"
    "level" => 0
    "past" => "0"
  ]
```

Hope Question is clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: make full array with zero values and then replace with data exists. it will be easy because index is equal to 'no'

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: do you know the max no in the `stats` array ??

Comment: yes @Maraboc it will be 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Initiate array with zero-filled values:**

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $arrayData[$i] = [
        "no" => "$i",
        "level" => 0,
        "past" => "0",
    ];
}
foreach ($stats as $key => $row) {
    $arrayData[$row->no] = [
        'no' => $row->no,
        'level' => $row->total_sent,
        'past' => $row->past,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know max `no` value, you need to get it. Then fill `$arrayData` with zero elements using `array_fill` function

```
$stats = collect($stats);
$arrayData = [];

$maxNo = $stats->max('no');

$arrayData = array_fill(0, $maxNo, [
    'number' => 0,
    'level' => 0,
    'past' => 0
]);

$stats->each(function($row) use(&$arrayData){
    $arrayData[$row->no] = [
        'number'   => $row->no,
        'level'    => $row->total_sent,
        'past'     => $row->past,
    ];
});
```